# How can I prevent the Ball from moving off of the edge of the screen? simple KeyListenerDemo example

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, keylistener

I have limited Java experience, especially when it relates to graphics. I've had very good help on this problem so far and hope to contribute more as I get familiar with this site. There is starter code (below) which works fine as I tested it in Eclipse. I'm using it from a class to teach a high school student. As per the instructions below in comments, would someone know an easy way extend the already simple program so that I can prevent the Ball from being able to move outside of the edge of the window? The ball moves fine with the arrow keys, but I can move it completely out of view/window still. Any simple ways to extend this demo program is much appreciated. Thank you.

.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;                            // #1
import javax.swing.*;   

/******************************************************************************
 * 
 * KeyListenerDemo.java
 * Demonstrates getting keyboard input using the KeyListener interface.
 * 
 * Program 18: Extend this program by adding a few more keystroke commands:
 *      z     (VK_Z)    - Cause the ball to jump to a random new location.
 *      s     (VK_S)    - Make the ball smaller - multiply its diameter 1/2.
 *      b     (VK_B)    - Make the ball bigger - multiply its diameter by 2.
 *      c     (VK_C)    - Change the color (in any way you'd like).
 *
 *
 *  In addition, modify the program to ensure the following:
 *  - The ball goes all the way to the edge of the screen but stays completely 
 *    on the screen. 
 *  - If a doubled diameter doesn't fit, make it as large as possible.
 *  - Be sure the ball never completely disappears.
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/
public class KeyListenerDemo extends JFrame
                        implements KeyListener      // #2
{
// Class Scope Finals
private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000;
private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800;
private static final int START_RADIUS = 25;
private static final int START_X = 100;
private static final int START_Y = 100;
private static final int STEP_SIZE = 10;

// Class Scope Variables
private static int x = START_X;             // x at center of the ball
private static int y = START_Y;             // y at center of the ball
private static int radius = START_RADIUS;   // radius of the ball

// Methods
/**
 * Create the window and register this as a KeyListener
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // Set up the JFrame window.
    KeyListenerDemo gp = new KeyListenerDemo();
    gp.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    gp.setVisible(true);

    gp.addKeyListener(gp);                          // #3
    // If this class had a constructor and you moved this line into
    //   that constructor it could not refer to gp since that variable
    //   is local to this method.  Instead you would write::
    // addKeyListener(this);
}

/**
 * Called when a key is first pressed
 * Required for any KeyListener
 * 
 * @param e     Contains info about the key pressed
 */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)                  // #4A
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x = x - STEP_SIZE;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x = x + STEP_SIZE;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        y = y - STEP_SIZE;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y = y + STEP_SIZE;
    }
    repaint();
}

/**
 * Called when typing of a key is completed
 * Required for any KeyListener
 * 
 * @param e     Contains info about the key typed
 */
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)                    // #4B
{
}

/**
 * Called when a key is released
 * Required for any KeyListener
 * 
 * @param e     Contains info about the key released
 */
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)                 // #4C
{
}

/**
 * paint - draw the figure
 * 
 * @param g     Graphics object to draw in
 */


   public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: basically you get the windows width, do `if(ball.x + ball.size > getWidth())` and you know whether the ball would leave the frame in its next step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set a max before you repaint:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)                  // #4A
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x = x - STEP_SIZE;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x = x + STEP_SIZE;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        y = y - STEP_SIZE;
    }
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y = y + STEP_SIZE;
    }

    x = Math.max(0, x);
    x = Math.min(SCREEN_WIDTH, x + radius);
    y = Math.max(0, y + radius);
    y = Math.min(SCREEN_HEIGHT, y);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: note sure but might have to add ball radius to x coordinate when checking for `Math.min()`

Comment: @Selim Yes you are right, my game making abilities have gotten rusty over the years! =/

Comment: Thanks a lot John and Selim. I'll give this a shot. My graphics skills are very limited - this has been a big help.